# The suggestions to the search filter in not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js\typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Sonstructs the suggestion engine
    var countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        // The url points to a json file that contains an array of country names
        prefetch: 'data/countries.json'
    });

    // Initializing the typeahead with remote dataset
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'countries',
        source: countries,
        item: 4,
        limit: 10 /* Specify maximum number of suggestions to be displayed */
    });
});
</script>
```

The above is my javascript and the below is my html code. When i run the script the autocomplete or the filtered item do not appear on the screen.

```
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <h2>Enter your country name</h2>
        <input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
    </div>
</body>
```

I think the prefetch in the script might have a problem. Can anybody help me with this ..

Comment: these are the errors poping in the console

Comment: typeahead.bundle.js:1705 Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function
    at Dataset.update (typeahead.bundle.js:1705)
    at updateDataset (typeahead.bundle.js:1882)
    at Dataset.reverseArgs (typeahead.bundle.js:968)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.each (typeahead.bundle.js:966)
    at DefaultMenu.update (typeahead.bundle.js:1878)
    at Typeahead.onQueryChanged [as _onQueryChanged] (typeahead.bundle.js:2069)
    at typeahead.bundle.js:2216
    at String.reverseArgs (typeahead.bundle.js:968)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)